# Error while trying to update edmx model from database

Tags: visual-studio-2013, model, edmx

I have 3 models in my project. 2 of them works perfectly fine.

But the third one keep giving me error while I try to update it from the database. I have latest versions of all 3 models. The error says that ___.edmx file cannot be found in your workspace or you do not have access permission to it. I tried re-creating the model , deleted it from the local and got latest version again but nothing worked. Also this model does not show the small lock sign in the solution explorer while the other models and files shows that. I am using VS 2013 Premium. I do not know whether this is TFS issue or Visual Studio issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Well done, getting the badge for the tour.
Please consider again the recommendation to make a MCVE.

Comment: @yunnosch What is MCVE?

Comment: It is mentioned in the tour, http://stackoverflow.com/tour you read that. At least you have the badge you got for doing so. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Basically "give us your toy, we want to play with it, too" but in a friendly way ;-)

Comment: It is a MVC Model. How can I re-create it here? I am getting that error when I try updating the model from database.